# How to distribute a Google Apps Script (processing Gmail mails) publicly?

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, gmail, chrome-web-store, gmail-addons

I developed a [Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com) to process some emails automatically (connected to Gmail), more or less like a bot, and it's working as expected. It runs every minute, using a `Time-driven` trigger `Minutes timer > Every minute`:

[image]

Is it possible to distribute this "script" for other users (including commercially), or will it necessarily be open-sourced? (note: Google Apps Scripts are using Javascript internally)

I see `Deploy as web app`, `Deploy as API executable`, `Register in Chrome Web Store`, `Deploy as web add-on`, `Deploy from manifest`, but I don't know which one to use to offer this service for other users.

[image]

Also, will it necessarily be on the *Chrome Web Store* or are there other ways to commercially distribute/grant access to a customer to such apps?

TL;DR: **How to distribute to customers a Google Apps Script that processes Gmail emails?** (that needs to run automatically every minute).

---

Note: It seems that Gmail add-ons are available here: https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/category/works-with-gmail. But it seems that we cannot sell an add-on commercially. Are Gmail add-ons necessarily free?

[image]

Note: the script is *not* linked to a precise browser or computer (thus it cannot be installed with a browser extension on a particular computer), it quietly runs on the Gmail server every minute.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [GMail Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/)

Comment: Yes @SandyGood but I see many deployment options in the menu shown here, so I don't know which one to choose to distribute to customers. Also I need the script to run every 2 minutes (it checks if new emails have come in a specific gmail label), is this possible with a commercial apps script / add on?

Comment: The only option is "Deploy from manifest"  None of the other options are for a GMail Add-on.  It's not a web app.  It's not an API executable.  Registering in the Chrome Web Store is for web apps as Chrome extensions, I believe.  The "web add-on" option does not have an option for GMail, only Docs, Sheets, Forms and Slides.  And it's definitely not an Android add-on, so the only thing left is "Deploy from manifest."  Public GMail add-ons are being restricted.   [You need to be approved](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQD9F5TXZvlpQcY1I6fvaZqLvULG1THhou3y5IpRRwjgwZYg/viewform)

Comment: @SandyGood Thank you. Where can I distribute my Gmail add-on when it will be ready ? The only place I see is: https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/category/works-with-gmail. But it seems that we cannot sell an add-on commercially. Are Gmail add-ons necessarily free?

Comment: You can implement a payment system in an add-on even though it's advertised as free.

Comment: You certainly can't run a time based trigger in an add-on more than once per hour, though. If you want that level of querying, use the addon to configure a cron service on your server for people who are paying you, and from your server run your functions via the apps script API. (etc).

Comment: @tehhowch Which kind of manifest file / trigger is used to run an add-on once per hour? I have looked at the doc, but I don't find a trigger to put in the manifest file that allows to run every x hours. I've only found things like `"contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddOn"
    }]`

Comment: @Basj Gmail add-ons only have the unconditional trigger available - i.e. they can only activate when the user opens a new message and then selects the add-on. Other add-ons (i.e. Sheets & Docs) can use time-based triggers. Ref: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions#wzxhzdk7wzxhzdk8use_apps_script_triggers

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

The page [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions) about Gmail add-ons states that they don't provide a direct way to charge users to install an add-on:

> We don't provide a way to charge users for installing add-ons, and add-ons can't include ads. However, you can roll your own payment system or call into an existing billing database. Your add-on can connect to non-Google services that bill users.

However, it's unclear for me if it's possible to run a time-driven background task (let's say once every 15 minutes) by a Gmail add-on. On the one hand, I see in the Restrictions page:

> You can't create or use Apps Script simple or installable triggers in a Gmail add-on.

and time-driven triggers seem to be included in "simple" or "installable" category, but I'm not sure. For example,  [`everyMinutes(n)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyMinutes(Integer)):

> Specifies to run the trigger every n minutes. n must be 1, 5, 10, 15 or 30.
>
> ```
> ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
>     .timeBased()
>     .everyMinutes(10)
>     .create();
> ```

On the other hand, I see an example [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/universal-actions) with so-called `Universal Actions`:

```
/**
 * Run background tasks, none of which should alter the UI.
 * Also records the time of sync in the script properties.
 *
 * @param {Object} e an event object
 */
function runBackgroundSync(e) {
    ...
```

Comment: As per example, `runBackgroundSync` will be triggered only by the user. If the user explicitly clicks on the universal action.